# Recursive tree search return wrong results

Tags: c#, algorithm, recursion

I have [this implementation](https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ITzD5) of a tree recursive function. It gets all possible paths from A to D.

The recursive function is:

```
private static List<Path> GetPath(int depth, Path path)
{
    if (depth == nodes.Length) 
    {
        return new List<Path> { path };
    }
    else 
    {
        var result = new List<Path>();
        foreach(var link in nodes[depth].Links)
        {
            Node node = new Node { Name = nodes[depth].Name, Links = new[] { link } };
            path.Add(node);

            result.AddRange(
                GetPath(
                    depth+1, path));
        }

        return result;
    }
}
```

The expected results should be:

```
A1-B2->C3->D4
A1-B5->C3->D4
```

However, the paths returned are the same and they include all possible nodes twice.

What's wrong with the function?

Comment: please paste relevant portions of the code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach(var link in nodes[depth].Links)
{
    Node node = new Node { Name = nodes[depth].Name, Links = new[] { link } };
    path.Add(node);
```

You probably intend to make a new path (which is a copy of `path`) for each node that you find here, before appending the next node.

Answer (score 1):

As @moreON's suggest, I add clone function into class Path, and modify the loop, in loop i copy to new instance of path:

```
public class Path : List<Node>
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        String s = "";

        foreach (var node in this)
        {
            s += node.Name + node.Links[0] + "->";
        }
        return s;
    }

    public Path Clone()
    {
        var newPath = new Path();
        ForEach(x => newPath.Add(new Node {Name = x.Name, Links = new int[] {x.Links[0]}}));
        return newPath;
    }
}

    private static List<Path> GetPath(int depth, Path path)
    {
        if (depth == nodes.Length)
        {
            return new List<Path> { path };
        }
        else
        {
            var result = new List<Path>();

            foreach (var link in nodes[depth].Links)
            {
                Node node = new Node { Name = nodes[depth].Name, Links = new[] { link } };
                var currentPath = path.Clone();
                currentPath.Add(node);

                result.AddRange(GetPath(depth + 1, currentPath));
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Hope this help.